# Select dynamic row data

Tags: vba, excel

I've never programmed in VBA before.

I need to reformat and sort data from a large report.

My code fails near the end. I've stripped all formatting away. I need to select and then sort based on one specific column. This report is of variable length. Some days, there will be data in ~10 rows, and in others, there will be data in ~10,000.

Some rows are empty.

Some extra details:

- I need Columns B through J.
- My data does have a header row.
- Sample code of the end of the macro is below (It's the hardcoded version. Anything not that exact size fails. I need the same functionality, but not to be limited to a fixed data set.)

```vb
Cells.Select
Range("J1").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("loc_can_pick_over").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("loc_can_pick_over").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("D2:D1237"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("loc_can_pick_over").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:AN1237")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: "...fails near the end."  How so, what error is thrown? What line is it on?

Comment: Any `Range()` call without a qualifying worksheet will default to the active sheet: is the sheet being sorted active when this runs?

Comment: @BruceWayne - The error comes when running that code on a sheet which has a different quantify of cells filled. Excel says, "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed. Debug takes you to the .SetRange Range("A1:AN1237") line of code.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Yes, the sheet being sorted is the active sheet when this runs.

Comment: Try adding the worksheet name before the range